# Handling Nest.js app on Redis cache store disconnection

Tags: caching, redis, nestjs

When I setup Redis as cache store like:

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';

@Module({
    imports: [
        CacheModule.register({
            store: redisStore,
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 6379,
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It works as expected. However, if for some reason the connection to Redis goes down, the whole application will crash:

```
Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 
127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
```

How can I gracefully handle these errors or even try to reconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it myself. I need to inject the exposed `CACHE_MANAGER` in the module constructor to get my hands on the client:

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

...

export class AppModule {
    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) cacheManager) {
        const client = cacheManager.store.getClient();

        client.on('error', (error) =>  {
            console.info(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: that logs the error, but NestJS is still crashed / not responding ... did you manage to fix this beyond just this logging?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle or you can check connections whether is connected or not. you can also use nestjs/bull module [Click here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues)

Redis Service Ready = queue.clients[0].status === 'ready'

Redis Service Disconnect = queue.clients[0].status === 'reconnecting'

```js
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { BadRequestException, HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Queue } from 'bull';
import CONFIG from 'src/config/config';
import { CreateEmailServiceDto } from './dto/create-email-service.dto';
@Injectable()
export class EmailServiceService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(this.constructor.name);
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue(CONFIG.REDIS_QUEUE_NAME)
    private mailQueue: Queue,
  ) {
  }
  async sendConfirmationEmail(user: CreateEmailServiceDto): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const queue: any = this.mailQueue;

      if (queue.clients[0].status === 'reconnecting') {
        throw new HttpException("Redis Service is unavailable!", 
         HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
      }

      await this.mailQueue
        .add('confirmation', {
          user,
        });

      return {
        message: 'Email Sent Successfully!',
        status: 201,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.logger.error(`Error queueing confirmation email to user 
          ${user.to}`);
      if (error?.response && error?.status)
        throw new HttpException(error.response, error.status);

      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the redisCache class as follows

```
redisCache.set('foo', 'bar', { ttl: ttl }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  redisCache.get('foo', (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // >> 'bar'
    redisCache.del('foo', (err) => {
    });
  });
});
```